# How to cause a timeout

Tags: sql-server-2008, c++builder, devart, c++builder-6

We are investigating a timeout issue and would like to replicate it as part of initial testing.

I am new to Devart, Borland C++ Builder 6 and SQL Server and unsure of the syntax required. I am looking for example code to execute a query or series of queries to generate an indefinite delay which will time out.

Comment: Did you ge solution ? not answer marked ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want a database command timeout, you can execute the SQL command:

```
WAITFOR DELAY 'hh:mm:ss'
```

setting hh:mm:ss to some time period longer than your application's command timeout